# How to add common headers using springdoc-openapi v2.2.0

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I use springdoc-openapi v2.2.0 to generate the swagger document.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Currently there are 20 APIs in this swagger document, 18 of them have some common headers as below:

```
                    {
                        "name": "channelId",
                        "in": "header",
                        "description": "Registered channel ID",
                        "type": "string",
                        "required": true
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "uuid",
                        "in": "header",
                        "description": "128 bit random universally unique identifier (UUID)",
                        "type": "string",
                        "required": true
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "businessCode",
                        "in": "header",
                        "description": "Business code",
                        "type": "string",
                        "required": true
                    },
```

But 2 of them don't need the headers.

Appreciate a lot if you can advise a solution using springdoc-openapi v2.2.0 to realize that the 18 APIs have the common headers but the 2 APIs don't have.